# AppleScriptTask throwing an error 5 - invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, macos, applescript, powerpoint, office-2016

I'm facing a problem on Mac 2016 Powerpoint. In my VBA module I need to run an applescript. As we cannot use MacScript anymore I followed RonDeBruin's explanation to use AppleScriptTask. My Applescript is working fine on his own but when I try to call it like this :

```
AppleScriptTask("hello.scpt", "myhandler", "hello")
```

With in my apple script

```
on myhandler(paramString)
say paramString
End myhandler
```

It gives me an error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument

my script is placed in Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Powerpoint is this path alright?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but I was receiving this error and the issue was the location of my AppleScript.

I originally had it under 
***/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel***
and I should have had it under my Library 
***/Users/username/Library/Application Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel***

Answer (score 0):

I did get that error originally but now it works for me with your stated folder location but only after I rebooted my Mac and tried the same script with Excel:mac 2016 (I'm not sure which action is responsible for the success). Interestingly, I thought that since Microsoft is very protective of their trademarks that I originally thought that the folder name needed to be "com.microsoft.Power**P**oint" but that did't work.

Comment: I rebooted my Mac but nothing change. Still the same error and if it works for you i really don't understand what's wrong. I will try with excel to see if it changes anything

Comment: I've rebooted my mac, i have tried with excel and com.microsoft.Excel file but it won't work either

Comment: did you just save the script from the editor by specifying the name without the extension? I found that it doesn't work if you add .scpt to the file name when you save or afterwards in Finder.

Comment: I saved it directly from the editor naming it just "hello" without adding an extension

Comment: I'm desperate here i really don't know what i am doing wrong :(

Comment: What version are you running? Mine is 15.18

Comment: Just noticed the parenthesis in the call. Are you assigning to a returned value or just calling? If the later, it should be this: AppleScriptTask "hello.scpt", "myhandler", "hello" but if you add parenthesis you get a different error so it's probably not the answer.

Comment: Also, if you edit the script from the com.microsoft.Powerpoint folder and add the test line, does it work? myhandler("hello")
on myhandler(paramString)
 say paramString
end myhandler

Comment: Yes i am assigning it to a returned value.

Comment: And yes it work directly from script editor with test line but not from vba

Comment: Version 15.18 at this end. I tried retval = AppleScriptTask("hello.scpt", "myhandler", "hello") and this works for me too. I get the feeling that messing around with folder names (upper/lower case 2nd P) + trying with Excel + rebooting kicked it into action because it did not work for me first time.

Comment: I tried a workaround launching a shell script that launches the applescript with this : 
Shell "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Scripts:com.microsoft.Powerpoint:test.sh" 
But it throws me an error 53 : file not found. Do you know anything about this?