# VBA Shell function throwing an error 53 - file not found on Mac Office 2016

Tags: excel, vba, macos, powerpoint, office-2016

I am trying to launch a shell script with in a vba macro on Mac Office 2016 powerpoint.

I've put this line of code :

```
Shell "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Scripts:com.microsoft.Powerpoint:test.sh"
```

It's working great in powerpoint 2011 but in powerpoint 2016 it throws me an error 53 : file not found

Is there anything different on 2016 to make this work?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

PPT 2016 on Mac is severely "sandboxed".  From within it, you can't access files just anywhere on the system as you used to be able to do.

Comment: So where in the system can i access files?
 Initially i wanted to use applescripttask but cannot get it to work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200331/applescripttask-throwing-an-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument

Comment: See if Ron DeBruin's page on this helps:  http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm

Comment: Using this certainly helped but now When i run the vba shell function it opens me the shell script in my editor (Xcode) instead of executing the script. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run a script in Offic 2016 is to use the new AppleScriptTask command but I think you've not managed to get that to work hence trying this route.

Comment: No i didn't, remember : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200331/applescripttask-throwing-an-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument