# AppleScriptTask in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

I followed the instruction of the page Run an AppleScript with VBA, I try with my custom script and I try to replicate the code of the example, but every time I receive the error:

> 'Runtime Error 5', invalid procedure call or argument.

I place the "Script.scpt" in the folder:

```
/Users/--me--/Library/Application\ Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/Script.scpt
```

The applescript:

```
on ScriptHandler(paramString)
return "You told me " & paramString
end ScriptHandler

#hereafter the body of the script

set lingue to {"Italian", "English"} set sceltaLingua to choose from list lingue with title "Lingua" with prompt "Select Language" default items "Italian" as string`
```

The VB Code

```
Dim myScriptResult As String
myScriptResult = AppleScriptTask("Script.scpt", "ScriptHandler", "myParam")
```

Does anyone never used this feature? Where is the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check [this[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994030/how-is-applescripttask-called-from-excel-365-vba-on-mac-mini-running-big-sur) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430056/pass-argument-to-applescripttask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass argument to AppleScriptTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430056/pass-argument-to-applescripttask)